# Finding the current RecordType name selected by user

Tags: apex, class, record-type

Updated code to give you more context of what I'm doing.

```
trigger vendorTrigger on vendor__c (after insert, after update) 
  {
    vendorController vencont = new  vendorController();
    vencont.PopulateWorkOrderBy(Trigger.new);
  }

public with sharing class vendorController
{       
      public void PopulateWorkOrderBy(List<vendor__c> vendor)
      {
          if('012g000000051uFAAQ' == getRecordTypeId('By Phone'))
          {
              //more work to be done....
          }
          else if('012g000000041xAAAD' == getRecordTypeId('By Fax'))
          {
             //more work to be done....
          }
      }
}
```

I able to get the `Id` (Thanks to @sfdcfox) of an `Record Type` name just by passing the `record type name` but the question is every time my code runs its always going to the very first `if condition`

here is my code:

//getting the record type id by passing record type name:

```
public static Id getRecordTypeId(String recordTypeName) {
    try {
        return Work_Order__c
               .getDescribe()
               .getRecordTypeInfosByName()
               .get(recordTypeName)
               .getRecordTypeId();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

//calling:

```
if('012g000000051uFAAQ' == getRecordTypeId('By Phone'))
{
  //more work to be done....
}
else if('012g000000041xAAAD' == getRecordTypeId('By Fax'))
{
   //more work to be done....
}
```

even though I have selected `recordType = By Fax` but still goes to first `if condition` which is `'By Phone'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to reference the RecordTypeId field of the sObject you are working with instead of using the hard coded SFDC Id in your conditional statement. In the code you published you never actually use the record type you have selected.

For instance you could do something like this:

```
public void PopulateWorkOrderBy(List<vendor__c> vendors)
{
    for (vendor__c vendor : vendors)
    {
        if(vendor.RecordTypeId == getRecordTypeId('By Phone'))
        {
            //more work to be done....
        }
        else if(vendor.RecordTypeId == getRecordTypeId('By Fax'))
        {
            //more work to be done....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `myAccount` is that instance of an sObject ?

Comment: I have updated my question to get you more detail like how I'm calling from trigger to apex controller.

Comment: This still looks like the answer, although you probably want to use `vendor.RecordTypeId`.  In your code, you're essentially asking whether the 'By Phone' record type's Id is 012g000000051uFAAQ, which (assuming that is correct) will always return true, regardless of the vendor__c record you've passed into the PopulateWorkOrderBy function.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the extra detail you added. I now use the list of vendor__c objects you provided in your recent edit. Hopefully this is more clear.